# Handle api calls authentication in scala sangria-graphql

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, graphql, akka-http, sangria

I'm developing an api gateway in scala with akka-http and sangria-graphql. The question is how can I ensure that all the api calls are secured?
more specifically I searched in sangria docs and came out to add some sort of middleware that handles this operation (in my case I should use OAuth2 and Google APIs).
But, since I'm not so experienced with this stack, I founded hard to retrieve some documentation or projects to study from.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: this is a bit old https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/sangria-auth-example but still gives you an example of how authentication can be handled. what authentication flow you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, I read something in the google docs https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_4 so I think that my server should receive an authentication code and then "validate" it. From your repo I see that I can build a middleware and then call google apis to validate the token and thus the client request. Hope it is understandable